# Ordering divs in css or js on safari 5.34.57.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Hi guys i am struggling to order the divs in safari ,the order property (-webkit) is working fine on chrome but is not working at all on safari any clues why 
I am trying to achieve something like this
   BEFORE

```
<div>
   <div class="first">I will be the second div in css</div>
   <div class="second">I am now on top</div>
</div>

AFTER(What I want to achieve)
 <div>
   <div class="second">I am now on top</div>
   <div class="first">I will be the second div in css</div>

 </div>
```

I've tried

```
 .second{
      -webkit-order: 1
   }

   .first{
      -webkit-order: 2
   }
```

Comment: `$('.second').insertAfter($('.first'))`

Comment: do u know any trick using css @Tushar ?

Comment: @WLedwaba flexbox order starts from 0, not from 1. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: @WLedwaba and also flexbox and it's order is not supported on Safari 5.

Comment: float:right not gonna work a want  div second to appear first vertically

Comment: @WLedwaba and also to use order you must have the parent container to have ``display: flex;``. So your only option is to use jQuery's ``insertAfter`` as mentioned in the 1st comment.

Comment: hmm oh but i think if u use any number greater than 0 in ascending it still gonna work @knitevision

Comment: cool let me stick insertAfter thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cool thanks insertAfter worked.

```
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 ) ) 
    {
               $('.second').insertAfter($('.first'));
    }
```